# Vue 2: Pegar valor do input sem usar v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Já estou detectando quando é pressionado o *enter* no *input*, como posso fazer para pegar o atual *value* desse *input* também? Não pode ser com `v-model`, pois preciso deixar um valor *default*, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

HTML

```
<div id="listas-page">
     @foreach($listas as $lista)
          <input type="text" value="{{$lista->descricao}}" v-on:keyup.13="editName">
     @endforeach
</div>
```

JS

```
var listasPage = new Vue({
    el: '#listas-page',

    methods: {
        editName(event) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Porque não podes usar v-model? Dá perfeitamente para colocares um valor default: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/92446/

Comment: É que estou trazendo vários inputs com seus respectivos valores do banco. E estou fazendo isso com um foreach em php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não recomendo de forma alguma essa mesclagem de php puro com vue, existem soluções melhores, mas é possível pegar o value pelo `event.target.value`, exemplo...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data : {
   value : ''
  },
  methods : {
    editName(event) {
      this.value = event.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input value="default" v-on:keyup.13="editName">
  {{value}}
</div>
```